# jquery call function with setInterval

Tags: jquery

I would like to call a jquery function directly on page load and than every 5 seconds.
For this I tried this:

```
doRequest(); // Call directly

setInterval(function() {
   doRequest();
}, 5000);

function doRequest () {
   // DO SOMETHING
}
```

It works !
BUT: Is this best practice?

Comment: What do you suspect might be wrong with this practice?  Performing an operation periodically on an interval is exactly what `setInterval` is for.

Comment: I only need need a confirmation, if this is correct :)

Comment: For reviews and feedback on working code, you might try the Code Review SE community: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of asynchronous operations, setTimeInterval will create long queue of requests which will be very counterproductive.

In case of time intensive synchronous operations, setTimeInterval may break the rhythm.

Also, if any error occurs in setInterval code block, it will not stop execution but keeps on running faulty code.Not to mention they need a clearInterval function to stop it.

Alternatively, you can use setTimeout recursively in case of time sensitive operations.

Comment: Is there any other queries or confusion?